# Clear user login list of gdm3 on wheezy - where is it stored?

Tags: gdm

I tried removing:

```
/var/log/wtmp 
/var/log/ConsoleKit/history
```

the completet gnome tree in /var/lib 
and accountservices

nothing helped. The user list ist still there.

We want to have a fresh box to give to the user when tests are finished.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late for the answer. Same situation. I succeeded truncatig  logs:

```
echo -n '' > /var/log/wtmp
echo -n '' > /var/log/btmp
echo -n '' > /var/log/lastlog
```

And removing files in accounsservice

```
rm /var/lib/AccountsService/users/*
rm /var/lib/AccountsService/icons/*
```

Then rebooting.

Probably not everything is needed...

Comment: confirming the first three lines worked.  Then restarted gdm on RHEL8